# How to use Asset API to access liquid file through shopify_api gem ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, shopify, shopify-app

I am new to the shopify app development and I ran into the problem while accessing the template file for example : **layout/theme.liquid** using the shopify_api gem.

I actually am able to setup the gem properly in the app and deploy it correctly. I can access the products and webhooks and also the whole asset list. see my code :

**Controller code**

```
class HomeController < ShopifyApp::AuthenticatedController
  def index
    # below three access for product webhook and full asset are working fine
    @products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, params: { limit: 10 })
    @webhooks = ShopifyAPI::Webhook.find(:all)
    @assets   = ShopifyAPI::Asset.find(:all, params: {"theme_id": 194896516}) 
    # not working below this line   
    @templates = ShopifyAPI::Asset.all(:params => {:theme_id=> 194896516}).find{|asset| asset.attributes[:key] == "layout/theme.liquid"} 
  end
end
```

**Template that renders the value**

```
<% content_for :javascript do %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    ShopifyApp.ready(function(){
      ShopifyApp.Bar.initialize({ title: "Home" });
    });
  </script>
<% end %>
<h2>Products</h2>

<ul>
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <li><%= link_to product.title, "https://#{@shop_session.url}/admin/products/#{product.id}", target: "_top" %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>

<hr>

<h2>Webhooks</h2>

<% if @webhooks.present? %>
  <ul>
    <% @webhooks.each do |webhook| %>
      <li><%= webhook.topic %> : <%= webhook.address %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% else %>
  <p>This app has not created any webhooks for this Shop. Add webhooks to your ShopifyApp initializer if you need webhooks</p>
<% end %>

<hr>

<h2>Assets</h2>
<% if @assets.present? %>
  <% @assets.each do |asset| %>
    <li><%=  asset.key %></li>
    <!-- <li><% asset.value %></li> -->
  <% end %>
<% else %>
    <p>This app has not created any webhooks for this Shop. Add webhooks to your ShopifyApp initializer if you need webhooks</p>
<% end %>

<h2>Template</h2>
<% if @templates.present? %>
<% @templates.each do |template| %>
    <li><%=  template.key %></li>
     <li><% template.value %></li>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
    <p>This app has not created any webhooks for this Shop. Add webhooks to your ShopifyApp initializer if you need webhooks</p>
<% end %>
```

I have also tried below variations on my controller but no luck

```
 @templates   = ShopifyAPI::Asset.find(:all, params: {"theme_id": 194896516, "asset[key]": 'layout/theme.liquid'})
```

Also

```
@templates   = ShopifyAPI::Asset.find('layout/theme.liquid',params: {"theme_id": 194896516})
```

I have set the scope properly for read_themes. I checked the [documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/Shopify/shopify_api/ShopifyAPI/Asset) and tried that too but couldn't succeed. Is there anything that I am missing or has the pattern changed over these years as the examples on documentation is not working.

The error I saw on the app is https://prnt.sc/jgglbf .

I hope anyone can help me with this. Really appreciate looking into this question.

Thanks

Comment: Hi guys, I got it, actually the problem was on the template. There should not be loop for the template.

Comment: Details post on accessing Asset API is explained http://www.navinbista.com/shopify-asset-api/